# Code convention about generic in Java

Tags: java, generics, coding-style

It might be a very beginner question, but I'm curious to ask. Usually I use `<T>` to write a generic Java class.

```
public class Foo<T> extends Bar<T> {...}
```

But I also see people use `<E>` in many open source project. Does `<E>` imply anything different from `<T>`? Or it is just some coding habits?

Comment: it's just coding habits. some may say T stands for type and E stands for Entity, or whatever, you can use any letter you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference, but these are the most common names:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> - E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
> - K - Key
> - N - Number
> - T - Type
> - V - Value
> - S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types

Answer (score 2):

`<E>` usually means an *Element* unlike `<T>` which means a *Type*. Check [Generics here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). This is just a *convention*.